# WebAPI 2.2 does not support substringof function

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I've a WebAPI 2.2 service with OData support.

My controller has an action which returns an `IQuerable<Entity>`, but I'm unable to use `$filter=substringof` function even if I allow all functions.

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery(AllowedFunctions=AllowedFunctions.All)]
    public IQueryable<Entity> GetEntities()
    {
      return GetMyQueryable();
    }
}
```

When I hit a URL like `http://localhost:49844/Entities/?$filter=substringof('Queen',Name)`

I get an error saying substringof is not allowed.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. An unknown function with name 'substringof' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "An unknown function with name 'substringof' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.",
        "type": "Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException",
```

Any idea why I might be seeing this error?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`substringof()` is a **V3** function while `contains()` is a **V4** function.

Try contains:

```
$filter=contains(Name,'Queen')
```

Comment: substringof() is a V3 function while contains is a V4 function. If contains not work, can you share the error message?

Comment: I was wrong to say 'contain'gave the same error. When using contain it says "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Function 'startswith' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedFunctions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.", But I think I'm doing this part. However, AllowedFunctions enum has not updated to reflect changes in functions for OData V4

Comment: @QianLi Thank you for pointing out the V3/V4 difference. I did not notice it. And since AllowedFunctions enum lists SubstringOf and no Contain there, I thought SubstringOf is still the way to go

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but this pointed me in the right direction, I still do not know what was the exact problem, but I created a new WebAPI and project, and it just supported contains function. Then I removed all the unnecessary NuGet packages in my original WebAPI and that seemed to fix the issue. No need to use AllowedFunctions enumeration, everything enabled by default.

Comment: This seemed to fix my issue, I was reading the wrong docs and google lead me here, thanks.

Comment: How do I use startsWith?  Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An unknown function with name 'startsWith' was found.